# How to retrive info from all checkboxes if they have same id?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have an Android application. In which I have ListView. List view is constructed by ArrayAdapter and layout file.
In layout file I have checkbox. So I want to see if all checkboxes are checked or not by pressing button. How I can do these?
Update: I want to see which checkboxes are checked

Comment: Check this http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of checked items in your list with the code:

```
private int getChecked()
{
    SparseBooleanArray checked = yourList.getCheckedItemPositions();

    return checked.size();
}
```

**Edit:**
To check that every item is checked:

```
private boolean isEveryChecked()
{
     SparseBooleanArray checked = yourList.getCheckedItemPositions();

     return checked.size()==yourList.getCount();
}
```

`yourList` is a `ListView`.